# File System Indexed Allocation

Tags: filesystems

I need to understand some elementary issue regarding to the Indexed Allocation method of FS implemetation.

For example:

If the block size is 2048 bytes and pointers to blocks are 32-bit, what is the maximal disk size that the FS will support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Block pointers are 32bit => you can store block numbers 0, 1, 2, ......2^32-1.
I.e. you will have 4G possible block numbers. Each block is 2048 bytes in size. So, the total data capacity of the file system is 4G*2K => 8TB.

Note that part of this space will go towards storing FS metadata (free blocks map, allocated blocks map, etc) to manage the user data that gets stored on the file system